# How to get result element from hibernate with no warning

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate I always do query, and get record from that like this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Product WHERE productCode=:productCode");
    q.setParameter("productCode", productCode);
    if(q.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }       
    Iterator i = q.getResultList().iterator();
    Product pp = null;
    if(i.hasNext()) {
        pp = (Product)i.next();
    }
```

But everytimes I used Iterator I have this Warning

> Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator should be parameterized

So I have tried to use
`Iterator< Product> getElement = q.getResultList().iterator();` but after that I have this new  warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type Iterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to Iterator

But after that I changed with `"(Iterator< Product >)q.getResultList().iterator();"` there was a new Warning :

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Iterator to Iterator

So I think that I am doing something wrong, but what? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out:

```
TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery("FROM Product WHERE productCode=:productCode", Product.class);
q.setParameter("productCode", productCode);
if(q.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}       
List<Product> results = q.getResultList();
Iterator<Product> i = results.iterator();
Product pp = null;
if(i.hasNext()) {
    pp = i.next();
}
```

Edit: I used this source http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute
Very Important:

> Both Query and TypedQuery define a getResultList method, but the
>   version of Query returns a result list of a raw type (non generic)
>   instead of a parameterized (generic) type

Comment: The warning is  on Iterator<Product> i = q.getResultList().iterator(); like I have wrote

Comment: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute Maybe the TypedQuery will solve the problem, because you can get a list that has a generic typ. In our case it would be a Product.

Comment: why are you using a List and then put the list in the iterator?

Comment: I changed the example on the objectDB side, but it also helps to see that we have a list of "products". We could now use the results for other operations too, but in your case it would be enough to use `Iterator<Product> i = q.getResultList().iterator();`